# How to fix bug with Cinnamon desktop slideshow?

Tags: cinnamon

I use ArcoLinux + Cinnamon. One time I found that my desktop background slideshow is turned on. But I didn't enable slideshow and it isn't even enabled in the settings.

When I change background settings (either background picture and slideshow params) they are running for 0-5 minutes and then all comes back. I tried to restart computer, to restart cinnamon (Troubleshoot section in panel context menu), to restore all settings to default (Troubleshoot section in panels context menu).

I also noted that in Melange Cinnamon Debugger no my background settings changes are logged.

Can anyone help with finding what went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Variety. I don't know how (maybe with the system upgrade) but configs changed to enabled slideshow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).